# custom authorization design in asp.net core 2

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, authorization, identity

Forgive me if there's already been a very similar post to this - I searched and did find "related" threads, but none that hit home, or it was targeting a different version of asp.net or asp.net core.  I just need some advice and pointing in the right direction.

My healthcare organization already has/uses a few OLTP systems for capturing patient data. I'm developing an Intranet that will consume the data from the various systems and present summaries/aggregations of that data for stakeholders. I'm developing the Intranet with ASP.Net Core MVC 2.0.

Being that the data is patient healthcare information, both Authentication AND Authorization are extremely critical.

For the intranet Auth, there's no point in reinventing the wheel - don't want to create the Auth layer from scratch.  The existing OLTP systems already have very robust Auth layers, with detailed User Info, Roles and Profiles.  Through Data Integration, I can get that User Auth data form the existing systems, store it in SQL Server tables, and then leverage it in the Intranet.

The question is, what's the best approach to accomplish that in a concrete manner.
Again, I already have all the necessary roles and profiles, I just need to be able to reference them in MVC to be able to:

1. Accurately authenticate users.
   Would this be best accomplished using EF in an AccountController?
2. Appropriately conduct Authorization (show/hide/prevent menu options, access links, pages, etc.).
   Would it be possible, or is it bad practice, to map the existing user roles and profiles to Claims in MVC via a    proprietary sql server bridge table?

Again, please know that I'm using ASP.Net Core 2.0... so please don't provide any example code snippets in 1.0. (The Auth architecture drastically changed between 1.x and 2).

Thank you all for your consideration and time.